How can I rig human-looking face onto a 3d FLAME mesh talking head?
Noob question here as I've just started working with Blender and 3d models:
I'm currently working with Blender 3.4.1 and I'm using Python script which runs blender on render.py and animates a 3d facial mesh. I would like to rig on a realistic looking facial head and was wondering how to do this in the Python API? Are there any ready-to-load faces out there in the wild that you can just tag on and make everything work? Here's what I currently have for render.py
import bpy
import os
import numpy as np
import sys

filename = str(sys.argv[-1])
root_dir = str(sys.argv[-2])

model_bsList = ["browDownLeft",
                "browDownRight",
                "browInnerUp",
                "browOuterUpLeft",
                "browOuterUpRight",
                "cheekPuff",
                "cheekSquintLeft",
                "cheekSquintRight",
                "eyeBlinkLeft",
                "eyeBlinkRight",
                "eyeLookDownLeft",
                "eyeLookDownRight",
                "eyeLookInLeft",
                "eyeLookInRight",
                "eyeLookOutLeft",
                "eyeLookOutRight",
                "eyeLookUpLeft",
                "eyeLookUpRight",
                "eyeSquintLeft",
                "eyeSquintRight",
                "eyeWideLeft",
                "eyeWideRight",
                "jawForward",
                "jawLeft",
                "jawOpen",
                "jawRight",
                "mouthClose",
                "mouthDimpleLeft",
                "mouthDimpleRight",
                "mouthFrownLeft",
                "mouthFrownRight",
                "mouthFunnel",
                "mouthLeft",
                "mouthLowerDownLeft",
                "mouthLowerDownRight",
                "mouthPressLeft",
                "mouthPressRight",
                "mouthPucker",
                "mouthRight",
                "mouthRollLower",
                "mouthRollUpper",
                "mouthShrugLower",
                "mouthShrugUpper",
                "mouthSmileLeft",
                "mouthSmileRight",
                "mouthStretchLeft",
                "mouthStretchRight",
                "mouthUpperUpLeft",
                "mouthUpperUpRight",
                "noseSneerLeft",
                "noseSneerRight",
                "tongueOut"]

obj = bpy.data.objects["face"]

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH'
bpy.context.scene.display.shading.light = 'MATCAP'
bpy.context.scene.display.render_aa = 'FXAA'
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = int(512)
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = int(768)
bpy.context.scene.render.fps = 30
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'

cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
cam.scale = [2, 2, 2]
bpy.context.scene.camera = cam

output_dir = root_dir + filename
blendshape_path = root_dir + filename + '.npy'

result = []
bs = np.load(blendshape_path)

for i in range(bs.shape[0]):
    curr_bs = bs[i]
    for j in range(52):
        obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[model_bsList[j]].value = curr_bs[j]
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(output_dir, '{}.png'.format(i))
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)


I'm guessing what I need to add is a face_obj = bpy.data.objects["human_face"] and also when it's time to render blendshapes I do a face_obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[model_bsList[j]].value = curr_bs[j] as well. This is over-simplifiying things but it seems like it's a common bsList, so the question is, does anyone know of any ready to load real heads that I can rig on top of the one I already have? If so, am I thinking of things the correct way as well?
Here's a picture of what the head currently looks like:
